# Optimization problem

Tags: math-mode

I am a newbie to LaTeX and would like to write this optimization problem using LaTeX code:

[image]

I would very appreciate it if someone could help me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you a starting point. This is how I may type this in TeX.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\var}{var}
\begin{document}
\[ \underset{w1,w2\cdots w_{20}}{\text{min}/\text{max}}\,w^TCw
\quad\text{subject to}\begin{cases}
(1) & w_1+w_2+\cdots +w_{20}=100\%\\
(2) & 0\%\le w_i\le100\%\quad\forall i=1,2,\dots 20
\end{cases}
\]

\[ \max_{w1,w2\cdots w_{20}}E[w_1R_1+w_2R2+\cdots+w_{20}R{20}]
\quad\text{subject to}\begin{cases}
(1) & \sqrt{\var[w_1R_1+\cdots+w_{20}R_{20}]}\le \sigma_\mathrm{max}\\
(2) & w_1+w_2+\cdots +w_{20}=100\%\\
(3) & \ell_i\le w_i\le u_i\quad\forall i=1,2,\dots 20
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was just wondering if you could one more time writing LaTeX.... this is so hard lol.

Comment: @JunJang Sorry, I don't understand " I was just wondering if you could one more time writing ". What precisely am I supposed to do?

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant "I was just wondering if you could help me one more time writing LaTeX". sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @JunJang Sure. But what?

Comment: I just added a new capture in the post. I would like to write the optimization problem in LaTex code too.